# Function in ruby code Logstash

Tags: ruby, elasticsearch, logstash

I have a logstash configuration file in which I am using ruby code. The code I'm writing is repetitive and I want to extract a function of it. Is it possible in logstash configuration file?

here is a part of my configuration file of which I need to extract a method of

```
  map_action => "update"
}

ruby
{
  code =>    "event.set('storeNumber', @@map['storeNumber_task1'])
              if @@map[event.get('storeNumber').to_s + event.get('txnNumber').to_s + event.get('tillNumber').to_s + 'startTime'] == nil and @@map[event.get('storeNumber').to_s + event.get('txnNumber').to_s + event.get('tillNumber').to_s + 'endTime'] == nil
                 @@map[event.get('storeNumber').to_s + event.get('txnNumber').to_s + event.get('tillNumber').to_s + 'startTime'] = event.get('logTimestamp');
                 @@map[event.get('storeNumber').to_s + event.get('txnNumber').to_s + event.get('tillNumber').to_s + 'endTime'] = event.get('logTimestamp');
                 @@map[event.get('storeNumber').to_s + event.get('txnNumber').to_s + event.get('tillNumber').to_s + 'counter'] = 1;
             elsif @@map[event.get('storeNumber').to_s + event.get('txnNumber').to_s + event.get('tillNumber').to_s + 'startTime'] > event.get('logTimestamp')
                   @@map[event.get('storeNumber').to_s + event.get('txnNumber').to_s + event.get('tillNumber').to_s + 'startTime'] = event.get('logTimestamp');
                   @@map[event.get('storeNumber').to_s + event.get('txnNumber').to_s + event.get('tillNumber').to_s + 'counter'] += 1;
             elsif @@map[event.get('storeNumber').to_s + event.get('txnNumber').to_s + event.get('tillNumber').to_s + 'endTime'] < event.get('logTimestamp')
                   @@map[event.get('storeNumber').to_s + event.get('txnNumber').to_s + event.get('tillNumber').to_s + 'endTime'] = event.get('logTimestamp');
                   @@map[event.get('storeNumber').to_s + event.get('txnNumber').to_s + event.get('tillNumber').to_s + 'counter'] += 1;
             else 
                   @@map[event.get('storeNumber').to_s + event.get('txnNumber').to_s + event.get('tillNumber').to_s + 'counter'] += 1;
             end
             if @@map[event.get('storeNumber').to_s + event.get('txnNumber').to_s + event.get('tillNumber').to_s + 'counter'] == 5
                @@map[event.get('storeNumber').to_s + event.get('txnNumber').to_s + event.get('tillNumber').to_s + 'totalTime']= (Time.parse(@@map[event.get('storeNumber').to_s + event.get('txnNumber').to_s + event.get('tillNumber').to_s + 'endTime']).to_f - Time.parse(@@map[event.get('storeNumber').to_s + event.get('txnNumber').to_s + event.get('tillNumber').to_s + 'startTime']).to_f).round(4)
                event.set('processingTime', @@map[event.get('storeNumber').to_s + event.get('txnNumber').to_s + event.get('tillNumber').to_s + 'totalTime'])
             end"             
}

date 
{
        match => ["logTimestamp", "YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS"]
        target => "logTimestamp"
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing that what you would like to do is store the value of `event.get('storeNumber').to_s + event.get('txnNumber').to_s + event.get('tillNumber').to_s` so that you don't have that printed over and over again. The answer is yes, that should work like this:

```
ruby
{
    code => "foo = event.get('storeNumber').to_s + event.get('txnNumber').to_s + event.get('tillNumber').to_s
             event.set('storeNumber', @@map['storeNumber_task1'])
             if @@map[foo + 'startTime'] == nil and @@map[foo + 'endTime'] == nil
             ..."
```

Comment: This is not what I'm looking for. I want to place all my ruby code in a method and call it in different if else clauses, currently I'm repeating the same code again and again in different clauses.  I want to know if it's possible to create a method of my code and call it from any if clause.

Comment: Something like this

 https://discuss.elastic.co/t/methods-in-logstash-ruby/102144/3